# Column Split without repeat

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with one column that I would like to split into several columns, but the number of splits is dynamic throughout the rows.

```
Var1
====
A/B
A/B/C
C/B
A/C/D/E
```

I have tried using `colsplit(df$Var1,split="/",names=c("Var1","Var2","Var3","Var4"))`, but rows with less than 4 variables will repeat.

From Hansi, the desired output would be:

```
     Var1 Var2 Var3 Var4
[1,] "A"  "B"  NA   NA  
[2,] "A"  "B"  "C"  NA  
[3,] "C"  "B"  NA   NA  
[4,] "A"  "C"  "D"  "E"
```

Comment: What would the desired output look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
> read.table(text=as.character(df$Var1), sep="/", fill=TRUE)
  V1 V2 V3 V4
1  A  B      
2  A  B  C   
3  C  B      
4  A  C  D  E
```

Leading zeros in digit only fields can be preserved with `colClasses="character"`

```
a <- data.frame(Var1=c("01/B","04/B/C","0098/B","8708/C/D/E"))
read.table(text=as.character(a$Var1), sep="/", fill=TRUE, colClasses="character")
    V1 V2 V3 V4
1   01  B      
2   04  B  C   
3 0098  B      
4 8708  C  D  E
```

Comment: As I said "better way of doing it" :) +1

Comment: I should probably admit that I'm pretty sure this is a trick I learned from Gabor Grothendieck.

Comment: This seems to work great on the sample data I provided, but when I test it on my actual dataframe it appears to fill vertically instead of horizontally. An idea why this may be? The actual data has numbers with leading zeros in place of letters, if this matters.

Comment: Leading zeros in all-digit fields can be a tricky issue. You may want to add colClasses="character" or you could add as.is=TRUE to the read.table settings. I'm not sure what "fill vertically" means.

Comment: By "filling vertically" I meant that it is splitting A/B to rows 1 & 2 instead of columns 1 & 2, similar to melt() I suppose. Thanks again.

Comment: Is there any chance you could post the output of dput() on the object you are passing to the `text` argument of `read.table`?

Comment: The whole column is 27k observations, but here is a portion if that helps.
"02628", "", "", "", "", "00730/02782", "02579", 
"00730/02782/03075", "00105",

Comment: That's not the output from dput(), but it makes me wonder whether there are problems with the separators being inside quotes.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your objective correctly here is one possible solution, I'm sure there is a better way of doing it but this was the first that came to mind:

```
a <- data.frame(Var1=c("A/B","A/B/C","C/B","A/C/D/E"))
splitNames <- c("Var1","Var2","Var3","Var4")

# R> a
     # Var1
# 1     A/B
# 2   A/B/C
# 3     C/B
# 4 A/C/D/E

b <- t(apply(a,1,function(x){
    temp <- unlist(strsplit(x,"/"));
    return(c(temp,rep(NA,max(0,length(splitNames)-length(temp)))))
}))
colnames(b) <- splitNames

# R> b
     # Var1 Var2 Var3 Var4
# [1,] "A"  "B"  NA   NA  
# [2,] "A"  "B"  "C"  NA  
# [3,] "C"  "B"  NA   NA  
# [4,] "A"  "C"  "D"  "E"
```

Comment: Thank you, this was exactly what I was trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

i do not know a function to solve your problem, but you can achieve it easily with standard R commands :

```
# Here are your data
df <- data.frame(Var1=c("A/B", "A/B/C", "C/B", "A/C/D/E"), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

# Split
rows <- strsplit(df$Var1, split="/")

# Maximum amount of columns
columnCount <- max(sapply(rows, length))

# Fill with NA
rows <- lapply(rows, `length<-`, columnCount)

# Coerce to data.frame
out <- as.data.frame(rows)

# Transpose
out <- t(out)
```

As it relies on strsplit, you may need to make some type conversion. See type.con